# Select rows to extract from a CSV file in USQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to extract a few columns from a CSV file.
This file is replaced every day and columns can be added to file.
My problem is that every time the number of columns change i need to update the USQL code... any help?

```
@billing =
    EXTRACT 
            id string, 
            company string
    FROM @companydatafile
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1);
```

That works on CSV file:

```
1, company1
2, company2
```

But if update the file to

```
1, company1, address1
2, company2, address1
```

That will return an error.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [How to deal with files containing rows with different column counts in U-SQL: Introducing a Flexible Schema Extractor](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrys/2016/08/15/how-to-deal-with-files-containing-rows-with-different-column-counts-in-u-sql-introducing-a-flexible-schema-extractor/)?

Comment: Yes, i´m trying to do it not using custom extractors, but seems that i have no choice...

Answer (score 3):

Another hint, in case you do not want to use a custom extractor but would like to use built-in extractors:

If you know that you evolve your CSV schema over time, use a way to differentiate between the different versions in the path name. Then you can use the following pattern:

```
@s1 = EXTRACT ... FROM "/data/v1/{*}.csv" USING Extractors.Csv();
@s2 = EXTRACT ... FROM "/data/v2/{*}.csv" USING Extractors.Csv();
....
@data = SELECT * FROM @s1 OUTER UNION ALL BY NAME(*) SELECT * FROM @s2 ...;
```

You can also wrap it into a table-valued function to abstract it. So you only have to update the function definition and using scripts will automatically get the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

David is correct - if you would like to run the same job for variable columns with no changes to the script, you should create a custom extractor. You can also automatically create an EXTRACT statement from a file using ADL Tools for VS ([blog here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/08/08/create-u-sql-extract-script-automatically/)), which means you can avoid delving through the file each time to get the new columns.

You can also vote or create a new feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake) to help increase the priority for developing this.  Hope this helps, and let me know if you have other questions.